# Saxon: Assignable depreciated time line

Tags: xml, saxon

We have lot of programs using Saxon: Assignable variables. I saw on the support page that it is getting depreciated. Any once can help us on the time line where it becomes completely unsupported?

Comment: As that is certainly something only supported in the commercial editions you would probably have better opened an issue on https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/issues but now that you have asked here I guess it is better to wait for Michael Kay to pick up your question here. Unless you are at XmlPrague where you could ask directly in the Saxon user meeting :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's deprecated because the semantics have always been a bit fuzzy, and we can't guarantee that a stylesheet that uses it will always work the same way in a future release: it makes the code dependent on the order of execution of instructions, which can easily change with an enhancement to the optimizer. We have no intention of actually withdrawing the syntax - though we might do so if it causes serious problems.

As regards Martin's comment, you're welcome to raise questions about the commercial editions of Saxon here, but we feel more of an obligation to actually respond if you raise the question on saxonica.plan.io - that's equally true for open source users.